# Convert array of Json to Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv

I want to generate a csv from array of Json data which I have below .

```
var keyDistribution =  [
                         [
                            {
                               "port": 4444,
                                "ipAddress": "52.35.15.121",
                                  "noOfKeys": 1
                                 },
                                 {
                                   "port": 2222,
                                   "ipAddress": "52.35.15.121",
                                   "noOfKeys": 1
                                 },
                                 {
                                   "port": 3333,
                                   "ipAddress": "52.35.15.121",
                                   "noOfKeys": 0
                                 }
                               ]
                             ];
```

How can I achieve this ?

I know how to generate a CSV from array as belows :

```
var data = [["name1", "city1", "some other info"], ["name2", "city2", "more info"]];
        var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        keyDistribution.forEach(function(infoArray, index){

           dataString = infoArray.join(",");
           csvContent += index < data.length ? dataString+ "\n" : dataString;

        }); 
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        window.open(encodedUri);
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");

        link.click();
```

But **can some one please help me out how can I generate this data from Array of Json data** (`keyDistribution` variable)?

**I want the output in format :**

```
[["port": 4444, "ipAddress": "52.35.15.121","noOfKeys": 1], ["port": 2222, "ipAddress": "52.35.15.121", "noOfKeys": 1]...];
```

**EDIT**
I just want the heading in the columns as required.
[image: The CSV Snapshot]

Comment: What you want is invalid - even though it is JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: Actually, there is no JSON. It is just an array (*of arrays*) of objects, instead of arrays. You can iterate through its keys using `for` and collect the same data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to iterate over this array of arrays of objects, like this:

```
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

// Iterating through 0th index element as it contains all the objects
keyDistribution[0].forEach(function (infoArray, index) {

  // Fetching all keys of a single object
  var _keys = Object.keys(infoArray);
  var dataString = [];

  if(index==0){
     [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
        dataString.push(inst);
     });
     dataString = dataString.join(",");
     csvContent += index < keyDistribution[0].length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
     dataString = [];
  }

  [].forEach.call(_keys, function(inst, i){
    dataString.push(infoArray[inst]);
  });

  // From here the code is same.
  dataString = dataString.join(",");
  csvContent += index < keyDistribution[0].length ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;

});
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
window.open(encodedUri);
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");

link.click();
```

Comment: Hi Void, I get an error for [].forEach.call(, function(inst, i){ saying Unexpected toke "," . Any idea what is the issue ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, check now.

Comment: That got resolved. But now I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: infoArray.join is not a function" error.

Comment: Thanks :) THat worked. 
Need a small favour. Can you also guide me like how can I set the header for the values that are being displayed in the CSV ? 

I have attached a screenGrab of my CSV in the edits section. 
I want Port, IP and the noOfKeys as the consecutive headings for the data. 
TIA :)

Comment: Done :) 
Thanks a lot once again :) 
And please do let me know about the header part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96800/discussion-between-fnaticrc-ggwp-and-void).

Comment: Thanks a lott man!! 
I wish If I could upvote this answer multiple times ! :) 
Really appreciate your efforts.